# Iterating Swap Algorithm Python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have an algorithm. I want that last solution of the algorithm if respect certains conditions become the first solution. In my case I have this:

1. First PArt

Split the multidimensional array q in 2 parts

```
split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
D = numpy.split(q, split_at)
```

Change and rename the splitted matrix:

```
S=B[1]
SF=B[2]
S2=copy(SF)
S2[:,3]=S2[:,3]+I
```

Define a function f:

```
f=sum(S[:,1]*S[:,3])+sum(S2[:,1]*S2[:,3])
```

This first part is an obligated passage.

1. Second Passage

Then I split again the array in 2 parts:

```
split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)]) 
D = numpy.split(q, split_at)
```

I rename and change parts of the matrix(like in the first passage:

```
T=D[1]
TF=D[2]
T2=copy(TF)
T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I

u=random.sample(T[:],1) #I random select an array from T
v=random.sample(T2[:],1) #random select an array from T2
u=array(u)
v=array(v)
```

Here is my first problem: I want to continue the algorithm only if v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]<=UB, if not I want to repeat Second Passage until the condition is verified.

Now I swap 1 random array from T with another from T2:

```
x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
l=np.copy(T[y])
T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
```

I modified and recalculate some in the matrix:

```
E=np.copy(T)
E2=np.copy(T2)
E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
```

Define f2:

```
f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])
```

Here my second and last problem. I need to iterate this algorithm. If f-f2<0 my new starting solution has to be E and E2 and my new f has to be f2 and iterate excluding last choice the algorithm (recalcultaing a new f and f2).
Thank you for the patience. I'm a noob :D

EDIT:
I have an example here(this part goes before the code I have written on top)

```
import numpy as np
import random

p=[ 29,  85, 147,  98,  89,  83,  49,   7,  48,  88, 106,  97,   2,
       107,  33, 144, 123,  84,  25,  42,  17,  82, 125, 103,  31, 110,
        34, 100,  36,  46,  63,  18, 132,  10,  26, 119, 133,  15, 138,
       113, 108,  81, 118, 116, 114, 130, 134,  86, 143, 126, 104,  52,
       102,   8,  90,  11,  87,  37,  68,  75,  69,  56,  40,  70,  35,
        71, 109,   5, 131, 121,  73,  38, 149,  20, 142,  91,  24,  53,
        57,  39,  80,  79,  94, 136, 111,  78,  43,  92, 135,  65, 140,
       148, 115,  61, 137,  50,  77,  30,   3,  93]
w=[106,  71, 141, 134,  14,  53,  57, 128, 119,   6,   4,   2, 140,
        63,  51, 126,  35,  21, 125,   7, 109,  82,  95, 129,  67, 115,
       112,  31, 114,  42,  91,  46, 108,  60,  97, 142,  85, 149,  28,
        58,  52,  41,  22,  83,  86,   9, 120,  30, 136,  49,  84,  38,
        70, 127,   1,  99,  55,  77, 144, 105, 145, 132,  45,  61,  81,
        10,  36,  80,  90,  62,  32,  68, 117,  64,  24, 104, 131,  15,
        47, 102, 100,  16,  89,   3, 147,  48, 148,  59, 143,  98,  88,
       118, 121,  18,  19,  11,  69,  65, 123,  93]
p=array(p,'double')
w=array(w,'double')
r=p/w
LB=12 
UB=155 
I=9 
j=p,w,r
j=transpose(j)
k=j[j[:,2].argsort()]
c=np.cumsum(k[:,0])
q=k[:,0],k[:,1],k[:,2],c
q=transpose(q)
o=sum(q[:,1]*q[:,3])
split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,UB-I]) 
B = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
S=B[1]
SF=B[2]
S2=copy(SF)
S2[:,3]=S2[:,3]+I
f=sum(S[:,1]*S[:,3])+sum(S2[:,1]*S2[:,3])
split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
T=D[1]
TF=D[2]
T2=copy(TF)
T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I
u=random.sample(T[:],1)
v=random.sample(T2[:],1)
u=array(u)
v=array(v)
x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
l=np.copy(T[y])
T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
E=np.copy(T)
E2=np.copy(T2)
E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])
```

I tried:

```
def DivideRandom(T,T2):
    split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
    D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
    T=D[1]
    TF=D[2]
    T2=copy(TF)
    T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I
Divide(T,T2)
def SelectJob(u,v):
    u=random.sample(T[:],1)
    v=random.sample(T2[:],1)
    u=array(u)
    v=array(v)
SelectJob(u,v)    
d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]
def Swap(u,v):
    x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
    y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
    l=np.copy(T[y])
    T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
    T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
    E=np.copy(T)
    E2=np.copy(T2)
    E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
    E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
    f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])
while True:
     if d<=UB
        Swap(u,v)
        if d>UB
           DivideRandom(T,T2)
           SelectJob(u,v)
           if d<UB:
              break
```

Comment: Well before we even get to the algorithm you have the following problems: you *define* `DivideRandom` then *call* `Divide`; you don't actually `return` values from your sub-functions; and `if d>UB` is missing a closing colon `:`. You never update `d` when the values of `v`, `u` and `T` change, so the loop will either never run (`d > UB`) or run forever (`d <= UB`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate indefinitely using `while True`, then stop whenever your conditions are met using `break`:

```
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    if count == 10:
        break
```

So for your second example you can try:

```
while True:
    ...
    if f - f2 < 0:
        # use new variables
        f, E = f2, E2
    else:
        break
```

Your first problem is similar; loop, test, reset the appropriate variables.

Comment: For the first part I need that: if v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]<=UB I want to continue if v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]>UB I want to recalcultate:split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)]) 
D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
T=D[1]
TF=D[2]
T2=copy(TF)
T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I
u=random.sample(T[:],1) #I random select an array from T
v=random.sample(T2[:],1) #random select an array from T2
u=array(u)
v=array(v)
and calculate the new: v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3] and verify again

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Are you saying you need further help?

Comment: Yes Please I really don't know how write it @jonrsharpe

Comment: I tried: def DivideRandom(T,T2):
    split_at = q[:,3].searchsorted([1,random.randrange(LB,UB-I)])
    D = numpy.split(q, split_at) 
    T=D[1]
    TF=D[2]
    T2=copy(TF)
    T2[:,3]=T2[:,3]+I

Comment: Divide(T,T2)
def SelectJob(u,v):
    u=random.sample(T[:],1)
    v=random.sample(T2[:],1)
    u=array(u)
    v=array(v)
SelectJob(u,v)    
d=v[0,0]-u[0,0]+T[-1,3]
def Swap(u,v):
    x=numpy.where(v==T2)[0][0]
    y=numpy.where(u==T)[0][0]
    l=np.copy(T[y])
    T[y],T2[x]=T2[x],T[y]
    T2[x],l=l,T2[x]
    E=np.copy(T)
    E2=np.copy(T2)
    E[:,3]=np.cumsum(E[:,0])
    E2[:,3]=np.cumsum(E2[:,0])+I
    f2=sum(E[:,1]*E[:,3])+sum(E2[:,1]*E2[:,3])

Comment: while True:
     if d<=UB
        Swap(u,v)
        if d>UB
           DivideRandom(T,T2)
           SelectJob(u,v)
           if d<UB:
              break

Comment: I can't get anything from unformatted code in comments. Please update your question with revised code and a clear explanation of what "Doesn't work yet" means.

Comment: Following your suggestion here I don't understand what your #use new variables are for.. In this situation my code at f-f2 print the same value @jonrsherpe

Comment: `f, E = f2, E2` sets `f` to the current value of `f2` and `E` to `E2`, so that when you loop you iterate the algorithm

Comment: Ok. But if I print before the while true the value of f-f2 and after the while true loop it's the same value. Otherwise if I run my code another time the value changes @jonrsharpe